# My code to check if I have Internet connection doesn't work well

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a code to detect if I have internet connection or not, and sometimes it doesn't work well. Here's the code:

```
-(void) webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    UIAlertView *alert= [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Couldn't connect to the Internet. Please check your connection." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];   
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

The problem is that sometimes a web doesn't load for other things and not because it has a bad connection. I hope that there's a better way to check the WiFi. Any idea?

Comment: Internet conniption, eh?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check for an active Internet Connection on iPhone SDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk)

Comment: you can check for WiFi connectivity and even for host reachability - check the link Josh gave you

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why I have written conniption... I think it has been the auto-corrector of OS X... Sometimes it does strange things...

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not seeing any code that checks for an internet connection, just code that shows an Alert.

Comment: I think your confusing the Notification Alert with Alert Views. That code looks great and is just what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you follow the link and read the best marked answer given in there. It worked perfectly with me.
[How to check for an active Internet connection on iOS or OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk)